# Will memory release if I stop debugging directly?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, memory-leaks, ide

I want to know, suppose I am debugging a code and at any point I allocated some memory and break point hits for example:

```
1: Statement to allocate 1 MB memory in **C**.
2: Any other statement where **BREAKPOINT HIT**.
```

Now my question is:

1. If I will kill my IDE (like visual studio) directly using task manager then allocated memory and resources will free or not.
2. If I will stop debugging then allocated memory and resources will free or not.

If yes then How can I confirm it whether memory and resources have freed.

Comment: what operating system? NT based OS yes, other windows version... no/yes(depends on type of the resource)

Comment: NT based operating systems windows xp.

Answer (score 4):

On modern operating systems, all the memory for your program is returned to the system when the program is terminated, which will happen in either of those cases. This might not happen on some embedded systems, but you wouldn't be running an IDE on those.

For other resources than memory, e.g., open files, devices, etc., the OS will generally reclaim all resources (unless they're still in use by other processes), but for some systems and some resources, under some conditions, resources can be lost or locked (which should be considered a bug in the OS or the device driver).

As far as determining that the system actually freed the memory, it can be quite difficult because the system allocates memory to buffers and swap areas and doesn't necessarily have a count of free space that you can check. For other resources ... if you can't acquire them then they weren't released.

Comment: If this is the reason the why memory leaks occurs.

Comment: @BharatSharma No, memory leaks occur *while* your program is running. Like I said, when your program is terminated, all memory is reclaimed by the system.

Comment: Why if you opens any camera or any share resource then it shows device in use when application crashes.

Comment: @BharatSharma Yes, on some poorly designed OS's the system can lose track of other resources if a program acquires them and doesn't explicitly release them ... but this isn't generally the case.

Comment: But I found in Android and Microsoft xp both.

Comment: Android is an embedded system.

Comment: Yes I agree but why memory leaks happen in any of the case while running program also because in both the cases process will terminate directly then according to your concept it should return all memory to operating systems in both cases.

Comment: @BharatSharma, you need to be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. From what you said, it seems to me that your problem is unrelated to memory leaks and you're looking in a wrong direction. Memory is released when a process is terminated on both the Android and Windows XP.

Comment: @BharatSharma a) cameras and other shared resources aren't memory. b) I'm having too much trouble parsing your bad English to make sense of it, sorry. You seem to want to have a debate ... there are other forums for those. This one is for getting answers to your questions.

Comment: I am talking about C and C++. Suppose I am running any code and allocated some memory. Now before freeing it I stopped IDE. According to you all memory should return to operating system. So It will return as soon as process stops(Acc to you). You told me that "memory leaks occur while your program is running". If program runs then also process starts. If I will stop process directly then It should return resources to operating system. If this is the case then memory leaks should not occurs but still they occurs. So again my question is at the same point. I just want to know the concepts.

Comment: @jim balter sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @BharatSharma Not all resources. Just one: memory. The OS automatically reclaims memory when a process dies. Other resources are a different issue and may be reclaimed by the OS or leaked, depending both on the OS and the resource type.

Comment: @JimBalter The Q mentions both memory and (other) resources - you might want to expand your answer to cover both.

Comment: @BharatSharma "If this is the case then memory leaks should not occurs but still they occurs." -- No they don't. What makes you think they do? "According to you ... Acc to you" -- look, go debate elsewhere; I don't need the rudeness.

Comment: @Angew It's too broad. For some systems and some resources, resources can be lost or locked, but *generally* the OS will reclaim all resources (unless they're still in use by other processes).

Comment: @Angew OK sir I understand that OS automatically reclaims memory this means memory leaks should recovers automatically. I also think that I should expand my question.

Comment: @JimBalter "For some ... lost or locked". That's precisely the sentence I think you should add.

Comment: @Agnew Ok, I've now followed the principle that the entire answer should be in the answer proper, not just the comments.

Comment: @JimBalter sir and So every times when we stop process directly then memory does not frees.

Comment: @BharatSharma I already asked you "how do you know"? You keep making dubious assertions. Also, if you stop the process in the debugger but haven't terminated it, then of course the memory isn't freed. Also, if the debugged program isn't a subprocess of the IDE, it may not terminate when the IDE is killed ... you have to terminate the program itself.

Comment: @JimBalter: On NT-based Windows versions, processes die when an attached debugger dies. Windows cannot continue to run them, as the state of the two is intertwined.

Comment: @JimBalter actually sir, first three lines and last three lines of your answer are conflicting. In first three lines you told all memory will be returned and In last three memory will not free. What I should accept and How this is possible that in two same cases, one of them memory will release and in another it is not.